# automatically generate a play using python

Tags: python, audio, auto-generate, voice-recording

To save a lot of work, I'm trying to generate a sound file of a script for a play that includes several different voices.  These voices should be computer generated.  I have software (NaturalReader13) for generating these voices.  Since I don't want the entire play read in one voice, I can't upload the whole text into NaturalReader and export it.

I could export several voice files and then mix them into a coherent whole, but this takes a long time and patience. I tried this already using Audacity to mix.  Instead, I want to automate this by interfacing with the program using Python.  I have no idea how to do this.

There are free voice generators online that would work for this task, but they are much lower quality.  If interfacing with NaturalReaders is too complex, getting the data from the web might be easier.

So basically, the script I have is of the form:

**Character:** These are the lines that need to be read...

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: I'm attempting this now using Automa.  I'll post a solution if this approach works.